# How does PWA jump to other web pages?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

How does PWA jump to other web pages? I jump to location href =./ xxx. HTML his address bar appears again. How should I jump to the other page

I looked for some answers. It seemed that it could solve it：

https://vaadin.com/pwa/learn/multi-page-pwa
“Load the ServiceWorker with a scope that covers the entire site
Link to the same Web Application Manifest from each page”

But I don't know what it means. Can you explain it in detail? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

> “Load the ServiceWorker with a scope that covers the entire site Link to the same Web Application Manifest from each page”

This simply means to use `"Scope": "/",` within a webmanifest that is used accross the entire PWA (paths, subdomains) without variance.